# Laravel relación Many to Many con relación adicional de la segunda tabla

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Tengo una relación de muchos a muchos entre una tabla **Orden** y una tabla **DetalleProducto**, en la cual guardo el color del producto y el stock. Sin embargo, al momento de imprimir la información, al ser el detalle una tabla complementaria del **Producto**, al momento de regresar la información, recupero los datos complementarios del producto, más no los generales.

Las relaciones las tengo de la siguiente manera.

modelo Order

```
public function order_details(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(DetailProduct::class, 'order_details', 'order_id', 'detail_product_id')
    ->withPivot(['quantity', 'size'])->withTimestamps();
}
public function coupon(){
    return $this->hasOne(Coupon::class, 'id', 'coupon_id');
}
```

Tabla DetalleProducto

```
public function product(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
```

OrderController

```
public function index(){
   $orders = Order::with('order_details')->with('coupon')->find(1);
   return $orders;
}
```

Y esta es la relación que recupero

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "user_id": 18,
  "coupon_id": 2,
  "payment_id": "ch_1IO4SBCM9PCsFBymvDhmu1wW",
  "last4": 4242,
  "brand": "Visa",
  "shipping_id": null,
  "total": 1098,
  "created_at": "2021-02-23T17:13:57.000000Z",
  "updated_at": "2021-02-23T17:13:58.000000Z",
  "order_details": [
    {
      "id": 9,
      "product_id": 3,
      "color": "Negro",
      "CH": 6,
      "M": 6,
      "G": 9,
      "unique_stock": 0,
      "created_at": "2021-02-05T15:43:08.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-02-23T17:13:59.000000Z",
      "pivot": {
        "order_id": 1,
        "detail_product_id": 9,
        "quantity": 1,
        "size": "CH",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      }
      **Aqui me gustaría traer la información del producto, es decir la relación entre Detalle y Producto**
    }
  ],
  "coupon": {
    "id": 2,
    "code": "10OFF",
    "discount_rate": 10,
    "state": "Activo",
    "created_at": "2021-02-08T18:11:08.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-02-08T18:11:08.000000Z"
  }
}
```

Comment: Y el método coupon ¿dónde esta definido?

Comment: No lo anexe, porque no es parte de mi problema, pero supongo que puedo anexarlo para no crear dudas adicionales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola No esto seguro pero puedes intentarlo asi

```
$orders = Order::with('order_details.product')->with('coupon')->find(1);
```

Si esto no te funciona creo que puedes hacer un modelo para la tabla pivot y extender la relación desde ahi, puedes documentarte aqui.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

Comment: Ayudaría mucho si le explicas tu respuesta y como es que le solucionaría el problema

Comment: solo remplazar la linea mencionada, lo siento no cuento con mucho tiempo ahora solo pasa por aquí si tengo chance responderé con mas detalle

Comment: Esto funciono perfecto, basicamente al poner el punto en la relación order_details, me permitio acceder a la relación del modelo de order_details con product

Comment: Excelente si evidentemente laravel te permite acceder a las relaciones dentro de relaciones de esa manera.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que llama a confusión el hecho que tu modelo Order declare el método `order_details` para traer la relación con `DetailProduct`. Yo le pondría derechamente `products_detail`

```
public function products_detail(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(
             DetailProduct::class, 
             'order_details', 
             'order_id', 
             'detail_product_id'
    );
    ->withPivot(['quantity', 'size'])->withTimestamps();
}
```

Y con eso sería más evidente que

```
      Order::with('products_detail')
```

Se trae para una orden el array de productos que se compraron (aunque en realidad sea el array de detalles de cada uno), el cual hoy figura como `order_details`, siendo que en realidad el `order_details` hoy lo obtienes en el pivot.

Como el detalle de un producto tiene una relación con `Product`, podrías añadírselo como:

```
      Order::with(['products_detail' => function( $query) {
          $query->with('product');
      });
```

Cuya salida tendría la forma

```
{
... // campos de la orden
  "products_detail": [
    {
      "id": 9,
      "product_id": 3,
      ..// detalles del producto
      "pivot": {
        ... // campos del pivote
      }
      "product": {
         id: 3,
         // campos del producto
       }
    }
  ]
}
```

Como observación al margen, me parece que, a nivel relacional,  `order_details` debiera relacionar `Order` con `Product`, y de éste llegar al detalle con una relación `hasOne` (suponiendo que un producto tiene sólo un registro con su detalle).